# Problem with underscan

Tags: video, config.txt

I just got my B+, and installed the newest version of Rapsbian. I am using an adapter box display it on my VGA monitor. For some reason, when I try to adjust the overscanning variables in config.txt, they don't change. This is my current config file:

```
# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
overscan_left=-30
overscan_right=-30
overscan_top=-30
overscan_bottom=-30

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
framebuffer_width=800
framebuffer_height=600

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=14

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
arm_freq=1000

# for more options see http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt
gpu_mem=64
core_freq=500
sdram_freq=600
over_voltage=6
```

Answer (score 1):

The setting `hdmi_safe=1` tells the Pi to use HDMI, it also sets a number of other options you don't want.

Whereas the setting `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` just tells the Pi to use HDMI even if no HDMI monitor is detected.

So:

1. comment out `#hdmi_safe=1` (add the `#`)
2. uncomment `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` (remove the `#`)

Reboot and you should get a picture. You should then be able to set your resolution for your monitor by adjusting the width and height values in the following two lines accordingly.

```
framebuffer_width=800
framebuffer_height=600
```

Full information can be found here: http://elinux.org/RPiconfig